# Auto Reloading Current page when checked radio button selected, Can somene please help me out

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

*Hi i want to auto refresh the checked page without refreshing the other page. I got two pop  up's which is working fine, i just want radio button to work fine when it's check. presently it's refreshing the page which is not checked after 10 sec, please someone help me. Swift response will be appriciated. Thanks*

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            setTimeout("timerefresh();", 10000);
        });
        function  timerefresh()
        {
            alert(document.getElementById('hdnReload').value + " Before IF");
            if (document.getElementById('hdnReload').value == 'MainPage')
            {
                var SelectedRadioBtn;
                var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("rdbOptions");
                for (var x = 0; x < radioButtons.length; x++) {
                    if (radioButtons[x].checked) {
                        alert("You checked " + radioButtons[x].id + " which has the value " + radioButtons[x].value);
                        SelectedRadioBtn = radioButtons[x].value;
                        //$('input[value ="lstScheduled"]').prop('checked', true);
                    }
                }
                setTimeout("location.reload(true);", 10000);
                $('input[value ="'+SelectedRadioBtn+'"]').attr('checked', true);
            }
            else
            {
                setTimeout("timeRefresh()",10000);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Try passing handler instead of calling, setTimeout("timerefresh", 10000);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setInterval instead of setTimeout and it will reduce your code.

`setInterval(function () {
    alert(document.getElementById('hdnReload').value + " Before IF");
    if (document.getElementById('hdnReload').value == 'MainPage') {
        var SelectedRadioBtn;
        var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("rdbOptions");
        for (var x = 0; x < radioButtons.length; x++) {
            if (radioButtons[x].checked) {
                alert("You checked " + radioButtons[x].id + " which has the value "
                    radioButtons[x].value);
                SelectedRadioBtn = radioButtons[x].value;
                //$('input[value ="lstScheduled"]').prop('checked', true);
            }
        }
        setTimeout("location.reload(true);", 10000);
        $('input[value ="' + SelectedRadioBtn + '"]').attr('checked', true);
    }
}, 10000)`

Comment: Hello, thanks for your swift response. I could able to reduce the code, but there is still problem when the page is refreshed. I got two radio buttons say B1 and B2, B1 is set to Selected= "true". Problem is when i enter the page B1 will be selected automatically and it will be refreshed but when i select B2 after 10 seconds, the alert shows the B2 value and after auto refresh it's going to B1 again which is not supposed to be. Please help me out

Comment: could you please post your code in the fiddle and paste your link here?

Comment: jsfiddle is not supporting ASP so changed your ASP code to html. I think it's working fine check and let me know is that working.  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BTV79/)